# How to get visitors geolocation (country and city ) using django?

Tags: html, django

i have a django project and need get visitors location using HTML5 (navigator.geolocation) , since im new with django , how to use and save navigtor.geolocaiton data in django ? anybody could help please?

Comment: Just the same way you'd do in php. Collect the location details and send to database. You can use Ajax to send the details to your backend .

Comment: @Chymdy thank so much, since im new with python/ajax could you please guide me with a little more details how send that location data to django backend using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

For the Ajax solution.
Create a view and URL path to handle the Ajax calls.

Do something like to make an Ajax call in the front-end...

```
data = {'longitude':97778, 'latitude':8947667}
$.ajax({url: "url_path", type:"post", data:data, success: function(result){
    <js code here>
}});
```

Now in your django backend, you can receive this data and then save to db like

```
def ajx(request):
    if request.method == 'post':
        <django code goes here>
    return HttpResponse("Saved")
```

Comment: thank you so much , could you please leave your contact here (email or skype)?

Comment: You can send me a message on ugahchymdy@gmail.com

Comment: thanks for your help , really appreciated ,  i pinged you on your email please check